# Error with bots Xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode9, xcode-server

My team decided to integrate our code with Xcode Server to use Continuous Integration. We use a Mac Mini for host the Xcode Server, and we can create bots without problems in this machine, but the integration proccess always fails.

We have in "Repositories" tab selected the branch where we want run the bot, and we get next error:

> Assertion: Configured project or workspace could not be found, it may
>   have been renamed or moved after the bot was created

How could we solve this? We didn't move the .xcarchive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue only changing the way to host locally the project. We have the project in SVN with trunk and some branches and I was downloading all project locally, so, after some tries changing the structure of one branch for test, I downloaded each branch separately. After this, I created the bot for each branch and now it runs successfully.

So, the solution is: Download separately each branch and trunk, and after create the bots.

Comment: Hi @Antonio, can you help me with this issue I am facing the same!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you created the bot from the same project workspace that will be downloaded from the repository.
i.e. Download the project locally. Open the workspace. Now create the bot from there.

Comment: I checked that the bot was create from the same project workspace. This wasn't the issue. But we change the way to get the projects to local machine and we solve this issue. I will post the way as answer.